# Arel Query CAST operation

Tags: sql, arel

I need to form a query in Arel which had a CAST operation earlier. The original query was like : 
    select * from tablename where tablename.anniversary >= CAST(STR_TO_DATE(?,'%d-%m-%Y-%k-%i-%s') as DATETIME)

(the question mark is replaced by actual date in further code)

For the where condition, I am doing this :

```
where(tablename['anniversary']
                       .gteq("CAST(STR_TO_DATE(#{date_value},'%d-%m-%Y %k:%i') as DATETIME)"))
```

The final resulting query that I should get should have :
    tablename.anniversary >= '2015-07-13 16:12:00'

But I get :

```
tablename.anniversary >= 'CAST(STR_TO_DATE(13-09-2015 05:33PM,\'%d-%m-%Y %k:%i\') as DATETIME)'
```

What am I doing wrong ?

Answer (score 3):

I'm not sure that understand your question, but...

First why don't you just use Ruby [datetime formating](http://apidock.com/ruby/DateTime/strftime)
? 
But if this date is a column:

```
Arel::Nodes::NamedFunction.new('CAST', [Model.arel_table[:column_name].as(Arel::Nodes::Quoted.new('DATETIME'))])
```

Comment: Arel::Nodes::Quoted('DATETIME') doesn't seem to work, says it's undefined

Comment: I edit it, thanks. It's Arel::Nodes::Quoted.new('DATETIME'), but if it works depends on your DB.